# Edit the glogin.sql in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

When try to edit the glogin.sql file and save it, it is saying that access is denied.

I logged into SQL*plus as a sysdba and mine is Windows machine. Please help me in editing the glogin.sql file and save the changes made to it.

Answer (score 1):

just edit $ORACLE_HOME/sqlplus/admin/glogin.sql with notepad and check if you can save it. sysdba is role for DB server and it is total different thing with editing files in client.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the permission to allow 'write' permission for the file 'glogin.sql'.